# Define annotation only applicable to static methods

Tags: java, annotations

Is there any way to define an annotation in Java that can only be used on static methods? For example, using:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.METHOD)
```

enables you to specify that the annotation can only be used on methods, but what about static methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no. But whatever code is processing the annotation can check that the method it's attached to is static.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats what I thought too. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I was able to tell, there's no annotation for ... annotations that targets specific scopes such as static, etc.

You'd have to validate that programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats what I thought too. Thanks though!