# Java Annotation only with static fields

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to define an Annotation in Java such that it can only be used with static fields?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778326/define-annotation-only-applicable-to-static-methods) SO question someone asked pretty much the same question, but about static methods. Is it the same thing for fields? Has anything changed in the two years since that question was asked?

Also, the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422390/retrieve-only-static-fields-declared-in-java-class) question shows a way that I could filter out just the static variables. However, I'm expecting the code I'm building to be used by other people, so I don't want someone to use the annotation on a non-static field and then not have it work for them. I'd really like to be able to give them an error in their IDE letting them know that the annotation can only be used with static fields.

Comment: As was suggested in the other question, your annotation processor can validate that, and report a warning/error if there's a problem.  A good IDE (e.g. Eclipse) will show that with the usual red underlining and a mouse-over message.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth as it seems like we're not going to get another answer, go ahead and write that as an answer so I can accept it.